# VBA (Excel 2007) how can I detect fill format of SeriesCollection?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

how can I detect fill format of SeriesCollection?
I know how to change it to solid > `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Fill.Solid`

and I know how to change it to Gradient > `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Fill.TwoColorGradient Style:=msoGradientHorizontal, Variant:=1`

But I dont know how to detect the current fill format...
Can you help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can test:

```
if ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Fill.GradientColorType = msoGradientTwoColors then
  'your code
```

you can **see the properties of an object in the debugger** (i had some troubles finding this one in the help). In this particular case, i was spying: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)`. Then, you can expand the properties to find which one apply to your case.

Comment: Where's the debugger you are talkin about? I was trying to find such a thing for over a month.

Comment: the easiest way is to set breakpoints in your code when you edit it. For more info, you can have a look here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debug.htm

Comment: I still dont get how u saw the properties of seriescollection... I can see the properties of ActiveChart and some of SeriesCollection's properties...

Comment: you need to set a spy on the expression you want to analyse, in your case: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)` (select the text in the editor and right-click > Set a spy...) then when you execute the code, if you set a breakpoint after the definition of your var, you will see the `+` box you can expand to find the properties

Comment: I dont have option of "set a spy".. I got the following options: cut,copy,paste,List properties/methods,List constants,quick info,parameter info,complete word,toggle, object browser,add watch,definition,last position and hide

Comment: You can `Watch value...` also. See [here](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/programming-excel-vba-debugging-for.html) or [here](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~tplacek/courses/3600/notes8c.pdf)

Comment: Nice! Checking out properties of objects in debugger is a great way to learn new things :)